# Gradually fade out a custom, map marker

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to gradually fade out a custom Google map marker.

I've seen all the posts that say to just use the drop in code from the DevBytes video and replace the setPosition with setAlpha, which is what I have attempted to do.

The problem is that whatever I do, my icon just goes white for the duration of the handler and then transparent upon completion, instead of gradually fading to complete transparency.

```
gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker marker) {
        if (marker.equals(myLocationMarker)) {

            final long duration = 1000;
            final int alpha = 100;
            final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                    float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);

                    float newAlpha = alpha - (t*100);
                    if(newAlpha<0)
                        newAlpha = 0;
                    int finalAlpha = (int)Math.ceil(newAlpha);
                    System.out.println("time = "+t);
                    System.out.println("newAlpha = "+newAlpha);
                    System.out.println("finalAlpha = "+finalAlpha);
                    marker.setAlpha(finalAlpha);

                    if (t < 1.0)
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 10);
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why not use a `ValueAnimator` instead?

Comment: prolly because he want to be able to run the app on API lower then 11

Comment: My min sdk is actually 11, so if there is a viable alternative solution I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: interpolators return a percent;  newAlpha = orignialAlpha * t;   if elapsed > duration return;  no other if checks are needed.  Experiment with other interpolators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried using ValueAnimator and it worked:

```
ValueAnimator ani = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1, 0); //change for (0,1) if you want a fade in
ani.setDuration(5000);
ani.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        marker.setAlpha((float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});
ani.start();
```

Comment: it should be `ValueAnimator ani = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1, 0); `because he wants to fade out.

Comment: marker.setAlpha((float) animation.getAnimatedValues());  //loose the final declaration on ani.

Comment: Generally markers on a map comes in the form of a list (Marker markers[]), are you applying an animation to each marker one by one?