# Google maps marker scale animation

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

I set some markers with custom icons on my Google map and I want them to zoom in and out while the user is on the map fragment. I saw that some solutions suggest that I should use a handler. But I wonder if there is a more "elegant" way to do so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28109822/3410697 here is an example of doing it without handlers

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and I'll inform you if it worked.

Comment: Since I work in Xamarin and the listener implementation is quite different, so I can't pass as parameter a marker object, on an architectural level your solution doesn't help me. Anyway, thanks.